# Replace white space from column name with underscore in DuckDB Python client API

Tags: python, sql, duckdb

I have a DuckDB table whose column names have white spaces, and I'd like to just specify a blanket rule that says "for all columns with spaces, replace it with an underscore". I know how to do this by converting the table to a Polars DataFrame, but can I do it without the conversion, preferably using DuckDB's relational API?

##### Sample data

`test.csv`

```
"id","company name"
1,"Walmart"
2,"Amazon"
3,"Apple"
```

```
df = duckdb.sql("SELECT * FROM test.csv")
```

This yields the `company name` column name with spaces.

```
┌───────┬──────────────┐
│  id   │ company name │
│ int64 │   varchar    │
├───────┼──────────────┤
│     1 │ Walmart      │
│     2 │ Amazon       │
│     3 │ Apple        │
└───────┴──────────────┘
```

##### Polars works

```py
df = duckdb.sql("SELECT * FROM 'test.csv'").pl()

# Replace spaces with underscores in column names using Polars
df.columns = list(map(lambda x: x.replace(" ", "_"), df.columns))
df_new = duckdb.sql("SELECT * from df")
```

```
┌───────┬──────────────┐
│  id   │ company_name │
│ int64 │   varchar    │
├───────┼──────────────┤
│     1 │ Walmart      │
│     2 │ Amazon       │
│     3 │ Apple        │
└───────┴──────────────┘
```

##### What I want to do

I'm unable to find any examples on how to do this directly, *without conversion to polars* in DuckDB's Python client API.  The [docs](https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/statements/alter_table.html) show how to use `ALTER TABLE` via raw SQL), but my goal is to do this via Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are ok with normalizing all non-alphanumeric characters in your column names, you can use the `normalize_names` [parameter](https://duckdb.org/docs/data/csv/overview#parameters) of the `*_csv_auto` functions

The python function `from_csv_auto`

```py
df = duckdb.from_csv_auto('test.csv', normalize_names=True)
```

The sql-like `read_csv_auto`

```py
df = duckdb.sql("select * from read_csv_auto('test.csv', normalize_names=True)")
```

This will replace the spaces with underscores.

```
┌───────┬──────────────┐
│  id   │ company_name │
│ int64 │   varchar    │
├───────┼──────────────┤
│     1 │ Walmart      │
│     2 │ Amazon       │
│     3 │ Apple        │
└───────┴──────────────┘
```

Answer (score 2):

A little more convoluted, but works in all cases, not just when reading a csv:

```py
import duckdb

con = duckdb.connect()
rel = con.sql('select 1 as id, 2 as "company name"')

names = rel.columns
names = [(name, name.replace(' ', '_')) for name in names]
projection = ", ".join([f'"{old}" as {new}' for old,new in names])
rel = rel.project(projection)

print(rel)
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution, it works for a parquet file I just read in -- thanks for sharing!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).